# How to get array in php while using post method through android http

Tags: php, android, arrays

In android code like this

```
for(int i=0;i<myArraListSize;i++)
            {
              ItemId[i]=myArrayList.get(i).get("iid");
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email[i]", ItemId[i])); 
            }
```

In php how to get the array value of email[i]

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) )
{
$email=$_Post['email'];
```

how to get the array values in php

Comment: make sure that you capitalize `POST` in `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: if you `print_r($_POST);` on the page what do you get?

Comment: `"email[i]"` doesn't look right. I would try `"email[" + i + "]"` or simply `"email[]"` in this case.